# core.logic: how to generate a repeated sequence of number?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to generate a sequence of number ((1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1, 2) ...) using core.logic:

```
(defn generator
  ([q] (generator q '()))
  ([q r]
   (lc/fresh [rw rws]
     (lc/conso 1 r rw)
     (lc/conjo rw 2 rws)
     (lc/conde
      [(lc/== q rw)]
      [(lc/== q rws)]
      [(generator q rws)]))))

(lc/run 6 [q]
    (generator q)))
```

But I'm getting this exception

clojure.core.logic.LCons cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection

If instead I replace conjo with conso:

```
(defn generator
  ([q] (generator q '()))
  ([q r]
   (lc/fresh [rw rws]
     (lc/conso 1 r rw)
     (lc/conso 2 rw rws)
     (lc/conde
      [(lc/== q rw)]
      [(lc/== q rws)]
      [(generator q rws)]))))
```

I'm getting the right result, but not in the right order:

((1), (2, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2, 1) ...)

Why am I getting an error with conjo but not with conso ?

How should I proceed to produce the sequence in the right order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Firstly, here's one approach that exploits the structure of your particular problem:

```
(defn generator
  ([q] (generator q '(1) '(1 2)))
  ([q x y]
   (l/fresh [x' y']
     (l/appendo '(1 2) x x')
     (l/appendo '(1 2) y y')
     (l/conde
       [(l/== q x)]
       [(l/== q y)]
       [(generator q x' y')]))))
```

At the REPL:

```
(l/run 6 [q] (generator q))
;= ((1) (1 2) (1 2 1) (1 2 1 2) (1 2 1 2 1) (1 2 1 2 1 2))
```

Note that this is perfectly efficient, because it only prepends items to lists.

#### Why didn't the original approach work?

On a superficial level, `conso` uses traditional Lisp cons cells represented using a type internal to core.logic. These are not regular Clojure persistent collections and `conjo` doesn't accept them as arguments.

On a deeper level, even if `conjo` accepted lcons cells as arguments, here it would actually be equivalent to `conso`, because `conj` (the functional counterpart of `conjo`) prepends items to lists (and here the lconses represent lists). This is because lists only support prepending efficiently; adding an item to the end of a list involves rebuilding the entire list and is thus an O(n²) operation.

Finally, even if `conjo` could append items at the end of the list, that still wouldn't work, because you'd get a sequence of

```
((1) (1 2) (1 1 2) (1 1 2 2) (1 1 1 2 2) (1 1 1 2 2 2) …)
```

In fact, you can do that with core.logic using `appendo` – try to put in `(appendo rw '(2) rws)` in place of your `conjo` call to see.

If you wanted to, you could take your original approach, replace the single use of `conso` with `conjo`, the `()` literal with a `[]` literal, and run `generator` to get a sequence of vectors:

```
([1] [1 2] [1 2 1] [1 2 1 2] [1 2 1 2 1] [1 2 1 2 1 2])
```

This is because vectors support efficient appending of elements at the right end.